# Как сделать абсолютно невозможной для нажатия область сайта?

Tags: javascript, html

Мне надо, чтобы АБСОЛЮТНО любое нажатие на какую-то область, которую я задаю, допустим координатами, не учитывалось, даже если EventListener висит на document.body. Мне надо полностью игнорировать клики по этой области

Comment: Вам придется во все слушатели добавить функцию, которая по координатам щелчка мыши понимала, надо ли прерывать событие или нет. Если говорить про клик на body, то данное событие надо будет переопределить и туда добавить фукнцию проверки. Остановить клик можно методом `.preventDefault()`

Comment: А если я пишу дополнительный скрипт с помощью tampermonkey и у меня нет доступа к коду сайта? Я могу как-то "взять" все слушатели и добавить к ним .preventDegault()?

Comment: Можете выкачать себе этот сайт локально и делать с ним что угодно. Вносить изменения на чужие сайты без доступа к их серверной части не получиться. Создания имитации с целью обмана пользователя уголовно наказуемая статья криминального кодекса.

Comment: Можно попробовать  - взять код события клика, превратить его в строку, далее добавить свой код, превратить эту строку обратно в функцию. Удалить старое событи клика и добавить новое с новой функцией. Код функции в строку - метод .toString(), как из строки в функцию превратить, [показывал тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1569375/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-socket-io/1569393#1569393)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 я не вношу изменение, я добавляю пользовательский скрипт с помощью расширения браузера tampermonkey. Т.е. я меняю сайт только у себя на экране для своего же удобства, что не несёт никакого вреда сайту и другим пользователям. И уж тем более это не имитация сайта. Прошу более тщательно читать поставленный вопрос.